# jQuery check CSS scale

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to check in jquery the state of the CSS value: transform: scaleX(0)?

```
if ($("#sidebar").css("transform") == "scaleX(0)" )
```

This does not work :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.css("transform")` returns a matrix like `matrix(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/z0g6j0sx/

Comment: You're right! I can just compare it with the matrix value. Thanks! :)